# Click to Redeem offer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, click, associations

I want users to be able to click on a benefit to add it to their profile. I put a redeem button on the benefits' show page and once a user clicks redeem, it should add that benefit to his profile.

Here is what I have

```
class Benefit < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_benefits
  has_many :users, through: :user_benefits
end

class UserBenefit < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :benefit
end
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_benefits
  has_many :benefits, through: :user_benefits
end
```

I need a link definition in the view that will save this association in the database. I can already make the association using the rails console.

```
<%= link_to 'Redeem!', "" %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following setup.

`rails g controller user_benefits new`

```
# UserBenefitsController
before_action :set_user
before_action :set_benefit

def new
    @user.benefits << @benefit
    redirect_to @user # maybe?
end

private

def set_user
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
end

def set_benefit
    @benefit = Benefit.find(params[:id])
end
```

In your routes:

```
resources :users, only: [] do
    resources :benefits, controller: :user_benefits, only: [] do
        member { get :new, as: :new }
    end
end

resources :users, :benefits
```

And finally in your view:

```
<%= link_to 'Add Benefit', new_user_benefit_path(@user, @benefit) %>
```

Comment: I'm close to making it work.
for set_benefit i am getting action controller exception saying: "Couldn't find Benefit with 'id'= ". any suggestions?

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake. Posting a fix ASAP

Comment: @NickyFeller, the updated answer, in the routes file, should work.